# Can I sell applications created using VS2008 from DreamSpark?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, licensing

My version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is downloaded from DreamSpark. Does my license include the rights to sell any created application?

I found : "you must use them in pursuit of increasing your education..." (https://www.dreamspark.com/FAQ/StudentOverview.aspx)

My main pursuit is to learn.

**Edit :**

1. Seems like I cannot actually sell applications. What about selling access to "premium"-suff on a developed server created with a DreamSpark-product?
2. Can I import VS2008-projects to VS2008 Express?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: OT : Is my edit of the post a good way to add on-topic questions? What do you suggest else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, IANAL, but some quick searches yield

[one here](http://www.labnol.org/software/microsoft-dreamspark-for-students/9481/) (**emph** mine)

> Microsoft licenses the software to you for educational use. This means that you can use the software without restriction for school assignments or personal projects. If you write or design something that you wish to sell, however, **you need to purchase a standard licensed copy of the Microsoft software before you sell your product**.

Perhaps use the [Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) instead? There aren't any restrictions here, except for the bits of VS missing from the free edition.

Comment: +1 for pointing to Express Editions

Answer (score 2):

how about writing in dream-spark edition and compiling release version on Express edition:)?

Answer (score 1):

[PERSONAL AND NON-COMMERCIAL USE LIMITATION.](http://www.microsoft.com/info/cpyright.mspx#EEB)

> Unless otherwise specified, the
>   Services are for your personal and
>   non-commercial use. You may not
>   modify, copy, distribute, transmit,
>   display, perform, reproduce, publish,
>   license, create derivative works from,
>   transfer, or sell any information,
>   software, products or services
>   obtained from the Services.

From the ***Terms of use section*** at the bottom of the Dreamspark page.

Comment: The key here being "non-commercial" - good spot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's nothing quite like producing commercial software "in pursuit of increasing your education", but I'm no lawyer.

Comment: this might, however put it in the "otherwise specified" category in the terms of use ;)